# How to include images in lib/assets on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

Currently, I have a external CSS library that I'm including in my rails app with the following structure

```
lib/
  assets/
    theme/
      css/
        *.css
      images/
        *.img
```

The CSS files refer to some images as follow:

```
background: #fff url("../images/image1.png") repeat;
```

This works fine locally, but when I deploy to Heroku this relative path ends up being:

...root_url/image1.png which doesn't work.

I could update all the image references to point to assets/ AND move the images there, but that seems tedious and I would prefer not to modify the CSS files since they are external.

Is there an easier way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SASS, you have access to the asset-pipeline helpers, like:

```
background: #fff url(asset-path('image1.png'));
```

If you don't have SASS or a pre-processor, you can use the non-versioned asset path directly:

```
background: #fff url('/assets/image1.png'));
```

Comment: Right, but then I need to modify the .css files which means if I ever want to update them I have to remember to re-apply the changes.

Comment: I see.  This is third party CSS with relative image links that are broken.  You could write a SASS or CSS based patch that over-rides the references to the images to serve them correctly for you and store that file separately.  Either way it's brittle on upgrade.